# Модальное окно bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, javascript

При создании модального окна bootstap оно закрывается сразу же после открытия. Внутри окна youtube видео. Как исправить? Окно открывается после нажатия не на кнопку, а на ссылку.

**Обновление**

Спасибо, что откликнулись! Не понимаю: через jsfiddle всё нормально отображается. Может конфликты? Я использую бутстрап в dle. Есть какие предположения? На странице я ещё использую fixed navbar http://jsfiddle.net/8hz1c733/

На всякий случай. Может, у меня устаревшая библиотека jquery? Либо нужно подключить что-то для поддержки html-5?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема с `<a href="#"></a>`, ссылка на открытие окна в новой версии бутстрапа работает через `data-target`, поэтому разработчики решили не блокировать работу обычной ссылки, и она при нажатии срабатывает.

**Решение:** убрать `href="#"`  из ссылки и задать cursor:pointer в css у элемента, чтобы ссылка выглядела, как ссылка. В принципе, тэг `<a>` теперь можно вообще не использовать для модальных окон.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8hz1c733/ - тут два раза один и тот же скрипт подключен, удали bootstrap.modal.js

В bootstrap.min.js - уже реализовано модальное окно. Получается, что скрипт срабатывает два раза: сначала открывает и потом сразу же закрывает, так как окно закрыто и была нажата кнопка модального окна.