# Отправка данных в БД в Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap, submit

Bootstrap 3.2.0, имеется модальное окно:

```
<a href="#add_position" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#add_position" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_position_btn">
    Добавить позицию
</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="add_position" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

С помощью скрипта пытаюсь сохранить данные в БД, но на выходе выкидывает на страницу `index.php?`, несмотря на то, что атрибут `action` отсутствует вообще.

Сама страница имеет вид `index.php?metall`, то есть идёт через `if( $_GET[ metall]){}`

Форма имеет `class="form-horizontal add_position"`.

```
$(function() {
    //twitter bootstrap script
    $("button#submit").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process.php",
            data: $('form.add_position').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                $("#add_position").html(msg)
                $("#form-content").modal('hide');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Как быть? Есть мысль о несовместимости jQuery, хотя всё остальное работает отлично.

Comment: Что при этом отвечает сервер проверяли? Статус код, тело ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно у вас [такая же проблема](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/356197/javascript-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE-bootstrap).

Также смущает вот эта строка `$("#add_position").html(msg)`, после неё нет "**;**", и в ней происходит замена модального окна сообщением, которое будет уже не в модальном окне, а где-то внизу страницы.

---

А вообще как-то странно вы показали куски кода:

- кусок html-кода с открытием модального окна;
- скрипт обработки формы (кода которой нет), и в скрипте закрывается совсем другое модальное окно `$("#form-content").modal('hide');` Откуда возникает этот #form-content, не понятно.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло! Проблема решена.

Comment: @Demixovsky, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).